# Number of questions for connectivity in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Assume we are given the adjacency matrix $G$ for some $n$-node graph. $G[i,j]=1$ if there is edge between $i$ and $j$, and $G[i,j]=0$ otherwise. Prove that the minimum number of questions we need to ask in order to find if the graph is connected is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, where a question is considered to check once in the matrix whether two nodes are adjacent.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I thought : asking the first node will take n-1 questions ,for the second n-2 ,then the total number of questions will be n-1+n-2+ ...1 which is n(n-1)/2 ,but I don't really think this is a strong proof

Comment: Minimum **over what**? Over all $n$-node graphs and all strategies for asking questions? I believe that minimum is $n-1.$ I don't think that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can do it in this many questions, just by asking about all the pairs. The difficulty is showing you can't guarantee to do it in fewer questions.

Hint for that: suppose before the game starts I tell you for free that there is at most one edge from vertex $n$. Given that information, the graph will be connected if and only if there is an edge from vertex $n$ **and** the graph on the remaining $n-1$ vertices is connected. How many questions do we need to decide these two things?

Comment: Can the contradiction come from the fact if we ask n(n-1)/2 -1 questions Let the last 2 nodes be X and Y and the question: is there a edge from X to Y won't exist, which proves that with n(n-1)/2-1 questions we cannot be sure

Comment: It's not as simple as that. Because you can choose which are the last two nodes based on the answers to previous questions, it's conceivable that there might be a way to do this so that you don't need to know about that edge. 

After all, if you ever find out that $uv$ and $vw$ are both edges of your graph, you don't need to ask about $uw$ because whether it is there or not doesn't affect connectivity.